# Mixed content error in loading a view from an HttpResponse() in ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, tabs

Before all, I precise that there is no trailing `http` in the code and my nginx server has no apparent configuration error. I find this issue very strange:

I got a main view with different tabs, each one being served by CBV. For example I call the content of the `company` tab with this HTML code:

```
<li class="">
<a href="{% url "staffpanel:companies:company_detail" company.pk %}" id='companyTab' data-toggle="tab">{% trans "Company" %}</a>
</li>
```

and it naturally calls this view which is loaded in the tab content `<div id="tabContent"></div>` with this code:

```
class CompanyDetail(StaffPanelMixin, DetailView):
    model = Company
    template_name = "staffpanel/companies/_company.html"
```

and the following js:

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('show.bs.tab', function (event){
    var tab = $(event.target).attr("id");
    var action = $(event.target).attr("href");
    $.get(action, null, function( data ) {
        $("#tabContent").html( data );
    });
    return false;
});
```

On each tab I can open a form into a modal block. This form calls an update CBV that let users edit the object displayed in the tab. The update view validation is as following:

```
class CompanyUpdate(StaffPanelMixin, UpdateView):
     template_name = "staffpanel/companies/_company_form.html"
     model = Company
     form_class = CompanyUpdateForm

     def get_success_url(self):
         return reverse("staffpanel:companies:company_detail",
                        args=(self.object.pk,))
```

For now, every thing is fine. If the form is not valid, data are correctly returned in the form contained into the modal block, displaying as expected the form with message errors. Thanks to this code:

```
$(document).on('submit', '#companyForm', function () {
    var form = $('#companyForm');
    var actionUrl = form.prop('action');
    var modal = $('#genericModal');

    ajaxform(new FormData(form[0]), modal, actionUrl);
    return false;
});

function ajaxform(formData, modal, actionUrl) {
    $.ajax({
        url: actionUrl,
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (data) {
            if (($(".has-error", data).length != 0) || ($(".alert", data).length !=0 )) {
               $(".modal-content").html( data )
            }
            else {
                modal.modal('hide');
                $("#tabContent").html( data );
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The issue comes with the success message. While it works fine in case of invalid form it failed to load the success url and raises a mixed content error and look for the view with the wrong protocol. I'm using SSL and it calls the detail view with HTTP instead of HTTPS.

I must precise that the update view does its job correctly as the data are updated. It's really a problem of returning the detail CBV.

Is it a bug? Am I doing wrong with js (surely)? Why can js load detail CBV in a case (loading tabs) and not after an update (as this is strictly the same view that is called)? Why does the url protocol change by the way?

NB: I tried to set SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER and SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT in django settings with no success. (I fell in a loop of infinite redirection).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that I wasn't able to load directly the page without having this painful mixed content issue (change of HTTPS in HTTP due to HttpResponse()).

So my solution was to return a JsonResponse containing the `success_url` and then I was able to load from `js` the tab.

I overwritten the form_valid in my update view as following:

```
 def form_valid(self, form);
      super().form_valid(form)
      return JsonResponse({'succes_url': self.get_success_url()})
```

and in my ajax call, I had to replace this line:

```
 $("#tabContent").html( data );
```

with this one:

```
 $("#tabContent").load( data['success_url'] );
```

and that's it.

Hope this helps !